# How do I display an image in a Flutter Web using Image.memory when I only have a Stream<List<int>>? data-type?

Tags: flutter, http, dart, web, multipartfile

Overview:

I am using the [file-picker library](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to allow the user to select one or multiple files from their device.  The selected files will have the ability to be previewed before the selected files will be sent for storage using HTTP/Multipart.

Problem:
The file-picker library returns a `List\<PlatformFile>` and I have access to either a `Uint8List?` OR a `Stream<List\<int>>?`

Setting `readStream` and `withData` to both True does not return both the `Uint8List?` AND `Stream<List\<int>>?` - This would be helpful in my opinion.

If I use the `Uint8List?` I am able to load the file using the Flutter `Image.memory` method but I am unable to use the `Uint8List` to use the `http.MultiPartFile.fromBytes()` because it only accepts a `List<int>`.

Alternatively, if I use the `Stream<List<int>>?` I am able to use `http.MultipartFile()` and pass in the `Stream<List\<int>>?` but then I am unsure of how to generate a preview of the file/image using a `Stream<List\<int>>?`

Things I have considered but not sure how to accomplish

1- Is there a way convert a `Uint8List?` to a `List<int>?`

2- Is there an alternative method for sending files using `Uint8List?`

3- Is there a way to receive both the `Uint8List?` AND `Stream<List\<int>>?` from the file-picker result?

I have copied a few snippets below but if you need more information please let me know. Thank you for your help in advance :)

Flutter Widget to Select Files

```
Text(
              "Open the File Browser",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: kPrimaryBlue,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              try {
                FilePickerResult? result =
                    await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                  type: FileType.any,
                  allowMultiple: true,
                  withReadStream: false,
                  withData: true,
                );

                if (result != null) {
                  for (var file in result.files) {
                    files.add(file);
                  }
                } else {
                  print('No Files Were Selected');
                }
              } catch (ex) {
                print(ex);
              }
```

HTTP Request to send files to endpoint:

---

> var uri =
> Uri.parse('https://hookb.in/7ZGKQE8ZDOua99D3RwMD');
> var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);

```
                  for (var file in files) {
                    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile(
                        "files", file.readStream!, file.size!,
                        filename: file.name));
                  }

                  var response = await request.send();
                  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                    print('Uploaded!');

                    setState(() {
                      files = [];
                    });
```

Widget to display image/file before submitting:

```
Image(
            image: Image.memory(files[index].bytes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I use the Uint8List? I am able to load the file using the Flutter
> Image.memory method but I am am unable to use the Uint8List to use the
> http.MultiPartFile.fromBytes() because it only accepts a List.

This part is incorrect. `Uint8List` implements the `List<int>` interface and can be passed to any functions/constructors that want a `List<int>`. Therefore, you can use the `MultipartFile.fromBytes` constructor. If you saw a typing error, it was likely because you didn't promote the nullable type to a non-nullable one.

```dart
MultipartFile.fromBytes('files', file.bytes!)
```